# Can any one Clarify Queries on HIVE 0.14

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

We are using Hive 0.14 in our application, when the execution engine is in MR, we are able to update ORC table , when we set Execution Engine has TEZ and perform insert /update /delete , it is throwing exception like 
"“Exception: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.LockException: Error communicating with the metastore
Killing DAG...
java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.LockException: Error communicating with the metastore
              at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Heartbeater.heartbeat(Heartbeater.java:84)
              at”"

When we run query which has Group by and Order By and Summation of numeric field,

TEZ execution engine show **+** before mapper number. what signifies **+** in the Hive command prompt while executing query. We see performance difference when we are executing query in Hive 0.13 and 0.14. Is this expected.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question - is it an intermittent error or a persistent error? Also, do you have the default metastore provided by HDInsight or are you using a managed one?

The + in Tez refers to the number of running tasks. The template of the Tez output is Finished (+Running) tasks.

Regarding the performance difference, can you elaborate more? How much perf difference are you seeing and is it persistent?

Comment: Its a persistent error. we were unable to perform update when execution engine is tez

Comment: Can you rerun your hive query with this setting as a prefix: set hive.support.concurrency=false; This will turn the new locking feature in Hive 14 off and help us identify if that is causing the issue.